# MSSQL - Database Mail XPs - Enable/Disable

Tags: sql-server, database, email

On MSSQL 2012 and MSSQL 2016 I use database mail for sending informations from alerts, jobs, etc. I disabled public a private profile and only DBO can send emails from MSSQL. But I still fight with security audit, because their SW tell them that 'Database Mail XPs' is enabled.

Can I set 'Database Mail XPs' so that this functionality will enable only when the alert or similar functionality needs send email as DBO?

I get from security audit this message: The 'Database Mail XPs' setting determines whether or not Database Mail can be started on the server. Database Mail is a Microsoft SQL feature that provides the SQL Server Database Engine the ability to send e-mail messages. Email messages sent by the database may contain sensitive data. As a malicious user may exploit this capability to transfer data to systems outside the environment, this feature should be disabled/restricted as appropriate to the needs of the business. NOTE: By configuring the 'Database Mail XPs' option to "0" you can prevent the Database Mail utility from starting. If Database Mail is already running when setting the option to a value of "0", it will continue to run until being idle for the amount of time stipulated in the 'DatabaseMailExeMinimumLifeTime' option.

Comment: If you need to be able to send mail, then Database Mail needs to be enabled. Having that enabled, however, isn't a security problem; it's enabling accounts that shouldn't have access to be able to, so I don't see what the problem is there.

Comment: What security audit? From an external company? What message?

Comment: I gave message to main body.

Comment: *" this feature should be disabled/restricted as appropriate to the needs of the business."* Notice it doesn't say "**Must** be disabled" It's *must* or **restricted**, which is exactly what I said in my first comment.